# Why doesn't vertical-align work properly when using float in CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How can I use the `vertical-align` as well as `float` in the `div` properties? The `vertical-align` works fine if I do not use the `float`. But if I use the float, then it does not work. It is important for me to use the `float:right` for the last div.

I am trying following, if you remove the float from all div's then it would work fine:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">First div, float left,  has more text.</div>
    <div class="left2">Second div, float left </div>
    <div class="right">Third div, float right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;    
    background: pink;
}

.left {
    width: 150px;       
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: yellow;  
    float:left;
    vertical-align: middle;  
    display:inline-block

}

.left2 {
    width: 150px;    
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: aqua;
    float:left;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    display:inline-block
}

.right{
    width: 150px;
    background: orange;
    float:right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Ujj/1/)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to set line-height.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
<span style="font-size: 38px; vertical-align:middle; float:left; line-height: 38px">Hejsan</span>
<span style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align:middle; float:right; line-height: 38px">svejsan</span>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VBR5J/

Comment: if you set `line-height` with same value for all elements the `vertical-align` is useless. (http://jsfiddle.net/VBR5J/448/)

Comment: Does not work for `<button>` elements. Instead of `<span>` is a `<button>`.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  vertical-align belongs on the CONTAINER (the `div`) not the individual elements.  The correct solution -- capable of vertical-aligning floated elements -- is to put both `vertical-align` and `line-height` on the CONTAINER:  `<div style="border: 1px solid red; vertical-align:middle; line-height: 38px;">`.  REMOVE `vertical-align:middle; line-height: 38px;` from the span styles.

Comment: Just discovered that what I suggest works for the floated spans in the answer's fiddle, but not for some elements (failed for a floated radio input).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve is right, but I understand why nobody gets it. You can do so many things with CSS per element and you've got so many ways to do it. It's hard to image that you'd set up a container to make it's children behave the way you want instead of the other way around.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve is wrong, and this answer is wrong. Vertical-align only applies to inline elements, inline blocks or table cells (the latter is just weird). Adding a 'float' makes en element a block element. Still, using line-height (and ignoring vertical-align) can be a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Edited:

The [**vertical-align**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align) CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline, inline-block or table-cell element.

Read this article for [**Understanding vertical-align**](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: It applies to `inline-block` elements too.

Comment: Updated. I've missed that. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: this isn't an answer

Answer (score 8):

Vertical alignment doesn't work with floated elements, indeed. That's because float lifts the element from the normal flow of the document. 
You might want to use other vertical aligning techniques, like the ones based on transform, display: table, absolute positioning, line-height, js (last resort maybe) or even the plain old html table (maybe the first choice if the content is actually tabular). You'll find that there's a heated debate on this issue.

However, this is how you can vertically align YOUR 3 divs:

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;    
    background: pink;
}

.left {
    width: 150px;       
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: yellow;  
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.left2 {
    width: 150px;    
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: aqua; 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.right{
    width: 150px;
    background: orange;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Not sure why you needed both fixed width, display: inline-block and floating.

Comment: Could you add some code to your answer in order to show how to achieve the solution?

Comment: Also, the "correct answer" is so easy to break... it makes me wonder how on Earth 19 people up-voted it.

Comment: the question said "he need the float:right on the last element", so he may need the last element to be along the right side of the container. how to achieve that goal in your answer?

Comment: Good answer, and besides so clear ! It just missing the Flexbox option.

Comment: This solution does not display the last item aligned to right. See: http://jsfiddle.net/eprky4q1/