# Image icons are not vertically aligned with menu caption

Tags: css, background-image

My menu with icons looks like,

[image]

Icons are displayed slightly above the text caption. I read the tips given here, to use [vertical-align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718134/css-vertical-align-does-not-work-with-float). And after specifying both `line-height` and `vertical-align`, it doesn't have any effect.

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Ku4UnPNEoGP2SqDJ5I7?p=preview).

How can i ensure the icon and the text item are vertically aligned?

Comment: `background-position: center;`?

Comment: hit the bull's eye!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try centering your icons within your `em` elements via the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property, which should cause them to be centered just as your caption text were and align properly (previously they were positioned in the top-left corner) :

```
em[class^='icon-'] {
   /* omitted for brevity */
   background-position: center; 
}
```

You can [see an updated Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XECl0BH0W7Qz8JostvZq?p=preview) and an example of what it looks like below ;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your icons are background images on a `50px` square element.  Just set the background to be centered

```
 em[class^='icon-'] {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   vertical-align : middle;
   line-height:50px;
   background-position: center; /* <--- this part */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    `a em  {margin-top:10px;}`
and see when you want the icon and change the value of `margin-top`